# Is it a good idea to downvote bumped questions with no response or effort by the asker?

Tags: discussion, moderation

The community user just bumped this:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/17593/why-cant-get-past-the-user-info-screen-when-installing-10-10

However the person was last seen when they posted it on Dec 15th and hasn't really responded to queries on his problem.

I was tempted to just downvote it since it's basically abandoned, this would effectively cause it to not get community bumped (right?). Is that sufficient or should we flag? The question's basically useless unless the person responds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't downvote it. If you strongly feel the existence of this question does not help anyone, flag it for moderator attention for potential removal.